# why image address must change when controller changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

in my sample  application (mvc4 razor) i have a picture in my root solution in directory like "\files\mypic.bmp" and i have a area named members and this area has a controllers "home"and "settings" .

```
controllers       actions     imageUrl             IE address bar
home              index     "\files\mypic.bmp"      localhost:3251\home
settings          home      "..\files\mypic.bmp"    localhost:3251\settings\home
```

when i use this image in home view i use this addrress of my image "\files\mypic.bmp" and explorer shows my pic but when i go to setting controller and home action i must use this address until explorer shows my picture ,"..\files\mypic.bmp" why this is and how can i make one address for all views and controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Url.Content` to get the relative path:

```
@Url.Content("~/files/mypic.bmp")
```

The issue is that, when you use relative paths like those listed in the OP, the browser interprets them as relative to the current URL.  Hence, they resolve to different places depending on whether the current URL is `\home` or `\home\server`.